# Group of order greater than 8 doesn't decompose into a direct product and Sylow 2-subgroup isomorphic quaternion group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, direct-product

Is there a group of order greater than 8 that does not decompose into a direct product such that its Sylow 2-subgroup isomorphic quaternion group $Q_8$?

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $SL(2,3)$ of order $24$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. 24 it is order of $S_4$, then 2-sylow subgroup exits. It seems to be isomorphic to $Q_8$. But how to prove it?

Comment: A Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4 $ is isomorphic to $D_4$ the dihedral group of $8$ elements (which is not isomorphic to $Q_8$). More precisely, $\langle (24),(1234)\rangle$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$.